# Как вытянуть тайлы в виде картинок с OpenSreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap, тайл, картография

где почитать, есть ли у них какое-то АПИ, чтобы используя запросы вида http://osm.com/get_tile?lat=44&lng=55 (к примеру) получать тайл некоторой заданной точки с заданным увеличением?
интересуют именно тайлы спутниковых снимков, не карт.
(в идеале - интересуют аналогичные решения и других открытых сервисов)

Comment: все еще актуально

Answer (score 2):

Пожалуй самое многофункциональное в сфере экспроприирования тайлов - [Тынц](http://sasgis.ru/sasplaneta/) ))

Comment: это мне известно, но мне не нужно десктопное приложение, мне нужны протоколы, - для внедрения на сайт модуля работы с разными тайлами для небольшой местности.

Comment: В каталоге SASPlanet есть папка \Maps\sas.maps\ в ней шаблоны формирования URL. Текстовый конфиг и "текст модуля" на чем-то Pascal-образном. Собственно больше протоколов там быть не может...

Comment: спасибо, погляжу...

Answer (score 1):

Вот [тут](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames) описано как lat, lon пересчитать в путь к тайлу, т.е. в ссылку вида [a,b,c].tile.openstreetmap.org/z/x/y.png

В качестве апи для сайта, посмотрите leaflet.js